# Stored procedure using sqlsrv php

Tags: php

I want to call an SP created in mssql.So i tried the code

```
$sql3="{call DietSticker(?,?,?,?)}";<br>
$Date='2020-06-25';<br>
$MealTypeName='Dinner';<br>
$stationName='4th FLR T1-NS1';<br>
$DietName='Diabetic Diet';<br>                                  
$params = array<br>
(<br>
    array($Date, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),<br>
    array($stationName, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),<br>
    array($DietName, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),<br>
    array($MealTypeName, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN)<br>
);<br>
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql3, $params);<br>
$res1=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt);<br>
var_dump($res1);<br>
```

But it returns `bool(false)`.

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump(sqlsrv_errors());` ?

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> array(6) { [0]=> string(5) "IMSSP" ["SQLSTATE"]=> string(5) "IMSSP" [1]=> int(-28) ["code"]=> int(-28) [2]=> string(51) "The active result for the query contains no fields." ["message"]=> string(51) "The active result for the query contains no fields." } }

Comment: You have your answer. *"The active result for the query contains no fields."*

Comment: What it means.?

Comment: It means your query / stored procedure did not return results for your given parameters - maybe you have a wrong parameter value which leads to no result, or there is just no result for this case.